Background image is not covering the rounded corners of Opera browser
There is a gap at the top left corner.


I tried with other images. Still it's the same. It's not the problem of the image.
import { useState } from 'react'
import './App.css'
import Navbar from './components/Navbar'
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom'

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <div className='bg'></div>
      <Navbar />
      <Outlet />
    </>
  )
}

export default App

.bg {
  background: url(./Assets/14731307_rm218-bb-07.jpg);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  padding: 0%;
  margin: 0%;
  border: 0;
}

